# Xcode 12.3 freeze on launch of SwiftUI project

Tags: xcode, swiftui

On launching Xcode the 'recent projects' list is shown without issue. Upon selecting my recent SwiftUI project, Xcode hangs and I have to force quit.

Creating a new project is not a problem.

If I create a new project, then navigate to file menu > open recent > MySwiftUIProcect, Xcode hangs again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting the directory at the following path solved the issue for me.

```
~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState/
```

Comment: Amazing! Feel free to mark this as the correct answer because it also solved the same issue for me with a SwiftUI project that caused Xcode to hang each time I opened the project - until I deleted this directory.

Comment: Ran into this issue today in a React Native project and this worked!